# Camunda 7 Docker task execution stuck at first task

Tags: node.js, camunda, bpmn

In my local development environment I run a Camunda 7 docker container (`camunda/camunda-bpm-platform`) for testing process automations. Sometimes when I start a process the token in the Camunda Cockpit just gets stuck at the first task without doing anything, not even an incident. This happens for external tasks which are then not found by our Node.js worker but also for DMN business rules, so tasks that don't have anything happening outside of Camunda.

This happens somewhat randomly and redeploying the process/DMN can fix the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Set `jobExecutorDeploymentAware` to false in the `bpm-platform.xml`.

Using the Diagnostics Guide provided by Camunda https://camunda.com/blog/2019/10/job-executor-what-is-going-on-in-my-process-engine/, I was able to see that the Job executor wasn't picking up the jobs queued in the `act_ru_table`. Specifically, it did not find them because the deployment ids didn't match what the executor was querying.

The same guide also mentions that a certain setting, `jobExecutorDeploymentAware`, should be *disabled* when deploying only via the REST API (which I did via the Camunda Modeler).

> If you do not use a shared process engine with process applications (e.g., you deploy processes only via REST API): Deactivate the process engine configuration property jobExecutorDeploymentAware.

The docker image has the setting *enabled* by default. To disable it I copied the contents of the `bpm-platform.xml` from a running `camunda/camunda-bpm-platform` container and changed the `jobExecutorDeploymentAware` property to false.

The settings file can either be copied into a custom image in a build. I just mounted it in docker compose instead using

```
   volumes:
      - ./bpm-platform.xml:/camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml:ro
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpm-platform xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform ">

  <job-executor>
    <job-acquisition name="default" />
  </job-executor>

  <process-engine name="default">
    <job-acquisition>default</job-acquisition>
    <configuration>org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration</configuration>
    <datasource>java:jdbc/ProcessEngine</datasource>

    <properties>
      <property name="history">full</property>
      <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate">true</property>
      <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
      <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">false</property> <-- !!! is set to true in the default config !!! -->
      <property name="historyCleanupBatchWindowStartTime">00:01</property>
    </properties>

    <plugins>
      <!-- plugin enabling Process Application event listener support -->
      <plugin>
        <class>org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.event.ProcessApplicationEventListenerPlugin</class>
      </plugin>

      <!-- plugin enabling integration of camunda Spin -->
      <plugin>
        <class>org.camunda.spin.plugin.impl.SpinProcessEnginePlugin</class>
      </plugin>

      <!-- plugin enabling connect support -->
      <plugin>
        <class>org.camunda.connect.plugin.impl.ConnectProcessEnginePlugin</class>
      </plugin>

    <!-- LDAP CONFIGURATION -->
    <!-- Uncomment this section in order to enable LDAP support for this process engine -->
    <!-- Adjust configuration, see ( http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-identity-service-the-ldap-identity-service ) -->
    <!--
      <plugin>
        <class>org.camunda.bpm.identity.impl.ldap.plugin.LdapIdentityProviderPlugin</class>
        <properties>

          <property name="serverUrl">ldaps://localhost:4334/</property>
          <property name="acceptUntrustedCertificates">false</property>
          <property name="managerDn">uid=jonny,ou=office-berlin,o=camunda,c=org</property>
          <property name="managerPassword">s3cr3t</property>

          <property name="baseDn">o=camunda,c=org</property>

          <property name="userSearchBase"></property>
          <property name="userSearchFilter">(objectclass=person)</property>

          <property name="userIdAttribute">uid</property>
          <property name="userFirstnameAttribute">cn</property>
          <property name="userLastnameAttribute">sn</property>
          <property name="userEmailAttribute">mail</property>
          <property name="userPasswordAttribute">userpassword</property>

          <property name="groupSearchBase"></property>
          <property name="groupSearchFilter">(objectclass=groupOfNames)</property>
          <property name="groupIdAttribute">cn</property>
          <property name="groupNameAttribute">cn</property>

          <property name="groupMemberAttribute">member</property>
          <property name="sortControlSupported">false</property>

        </properties>
      </plugin>
      -->

      <!-- LDAP CONFIGURATION -->
      <!-- The following plugin allows you to grant administrator authorizations to an existing LDAP user -->
      <!--
      <plugin>
        <class>org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.plugin.AdministratorAuthorizationPlugin</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="administratorUserName">admin</property>
        </properties>
      </plugin>
      -->

    </plugins>


  </process-engine>

</bpm-platform>
```